# Setting ContextMenu Style to 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm trying to change the default style of the contextmenu to 2013/2015 in my rehosted vs13 application.

The problem occurs in only one designer, everywhere else its the correct one. I've tried to override both [the XAML code](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/contextmenu/) and the code behind, checked if something else was changing the style, but without anykind of result.

Is there even a way to change the default style? Am I overseeing something?

Comment: What do you mean by 2013 context menu style?

Comment: The context menu when you right click on the element is in the windows 2008 style, but the rest of the application is in 2013 style.

Comment: What is Windows 2008 and 2013?

Comment: The ContextMenu apperance is not dictated by the operating system; it is entirely controlled by WPF.

Comment: I meant the Visual Studio 2008 and 2013 style. I know that its controlled by WPF, I'm trying to find out how to change it from one Visual Studio style to another.

Comment: Why would your WPF application take a ContextMenu style from Visual Studio....?

Comment: Because I'm using a rehosted designer of visual studio 2013, what means that everything is in the Visual Studio 2013 style, except that one element, which is in the Visual Studio 2008 style. I already tried to change it in the XAML and the code behind, but nothing changed when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some heavy research/try and error if finally found out what was wrong: I couldnt access the control I wanted to change the ordinary way, so I had to think outside of the box (and ask a collegue for help).

This is the code that works for me, its not pretty, but it deletes the 'standard'-style set by WPF.

```
var dv = wd.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
dv.MenuItemStyle = null;
dv.MenuSeparatorStyle = null;
dv.Resources[typeof(ContextMenu)] = new Style(typeof(ContextMenu));
```

Quick thanks to Glen Thomas for trying to help.